# Improve pagin count method speed with Linq on large amount of data

Tags: c#, .net, linq, count, pagination

I'have a count method to paginate a grid, that return a number around 2 millions, I wan't to improve it speed with a query like this, but on Linq:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS Row, Id
FROM myTable ) t
WHERE Row between 0 and (pageSize*visiblePages)+1 -- The number 1 is to check if there is another set of 1 or more pages
```

My problem is, I don't need to count 2 millions for a page that will show that I have 11 pages. The method to retrieve only 10 results works fine, but I can't count with the row_number

Comment: _I don't need to count 2 millions for a page that will show that I have 11 pages._ Can you be a little more clear? You don't need to count if you aren't calculating how many pages there are, you do otherwise.

Comment: Why not just perform a select count(*) from myTable and see if the count(*) is > pageSize*visiblePages

Comment: The problem is that the count() from myTable is slow, it takes more than 20 seconds. The columns is indexed, but I have to make some joins to do the count.

I don't need to know that there are more pages that I show on each page.

Example, I have 30 pages on DB, but my current page shows from page 1 to page 10, I don't need a count that is higher than 100 (10 pages, 10 results per page)

Comment: Count(*) is not going to be slower than ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS Row, Id

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use LINQ's `Take` or `Skip` like this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386988%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Also check this VS gallery's pager control for MVC: http://en.webdiyer.com/